# How to merge documents in activiti

Tags: alfresco, enterprise, activiti, spring-bean

I am using Activiti enterprise and I want to merge 2 documents within the workflow... I tried document merge bean specified here,

https://docs.alfresco.com/activiti/docs/dev-guide/1.4.0/#_document_merge_bean_documentmergebean

But neither it merge documents nor gives any error, But in tomacat console I can see following output

```
INFO com.activiti.runtime.activiti.bean.DocumentMergeBean - fieldIds t1,t2,       variable t3 305347
INFO com.activiti.runtime.activiti.bean.DocumentMergeBean - contentList 1000
INFO com.activiti.runtime.activiti.bean.DocumentMergeBean - field t2
INFO com.activiti.runtime.activiti.bean.DocumentMergeBean - putting t2 1
INFO com.activiti.runtime.activiti.bean.DocumentMergeBean - field t1
INFO com.activiti.runtime.activiti.bean.DocumentMergeBean - putting t1 1
INFO com.activiti.runtime.activiti.bean.DocumentMergeBean - finalContentList 0
```

here t1 and t2 are my 2 document variables and I am trying to get output in variable t3 but bad luck...

Please help if anyone knows...

Answer (score 1):

DocumentMergeBean only works for .doc and .docx files.
Are the filenames of the files you are trying to merge of type .doc or .docx?

The specific code lines that enforce this behavior are below:

```
for (RelatedContent relatedContent : fieldContentList) {
    if (relatedContent.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith("docx") || 
        relatedContent.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith("doc")) {
           finalContentList.add(relatedContent);
   }
}
```

Hope this helps,
Greg

Comment: Yes, both the documents are of .docx I am calling the merge bean from my service task like this,                    
${documentMergeBean.mergeDocuments('t1,t2', 't3', execution)}
in the expression property Is this a correct way? or am I making some mistake here?

Comment: I believe you are calling correctly, but I believe the field (t1, and t2 in your case) names need themselves to map to the name ( of the related content).

Try querying the RELATED_CONTENT table and make sure the records for this task have a name that ends with .doc or .docx

Comment: Hey Greg,
Thank you so much for your time... I really appreciate that... Actually there is typo in developer guide... we need to use ";" instead of "," in the expression... ${documentMergeBean.mergeDocuments('t1;t2', 't3', execution)}